# Express js Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, imap

When my code is like this, the rendering is early. I want the above processes to run first and then the rendering process (promise).
What should I do to fix the problem?

```js
app.get('/inbox', (req, res) => {
  var messagesList = {
    messages: [],
    subjects: [],
    dates: [],
    from: []
  };
  imaps.connect(config).then(function(connection) {

    connection.openBox('INBOX', (err, box) => {

      console.log(box.messages)
      res.locals.box_messages = box.messages;
      var searchCriteria = ['1:' + box.messages.total];
      var fetchOptions = {
        bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT', ''],
      };

      connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function(messages) {

        messages.forEach(function(item) {

          var all = _.find(item.parts, {
            "which": ""
          })
          var id = item.attributes.uid;
          var idHeader = "Imap-Id: " + id + "\r\n";
          simpleParser(idHeader + all.body, (err, mail) => {

            messagesList.messages.push(mail.html)
            messagesList.subjects.push(mail.subject)
            messagesList.dates.push(mail.date)
            messagesList.messages.push(mail.from.text)
            res.locals.messagesList = messagesList
          })
        })
      })
    })

  })
  res.render('index')
})
```

Comment: Put `res.render('index')` inside the `connection.search()` promise callback.

Comment: Hello, i put .then(() =>{
            console.log('worked render')
            res.render('index')
        })
but the code errors  still render first then mail parser happens

Comment: @code - That's not going to be enough because of the `.forEach()` loop that has an asynchronous operation inside it.

Comment: Then instead of a loop, use function recursion so you can return a promise... async works!

Comment: hello, i add return new promise under from foreach and resolve it from mailparser callback and then(()=>{console.log('promise worked')}) from end foreach but still errors

Comment: Do you ever close this imap connection?

Comment: yes ,
I don't think the error is related to that.

Comment: I know it's not related to that - I'm pointing out another problem with your code.  That's why I commented rather than answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the forEach for a map and make simpleParser asyncronic so it will wait for it to finish before rendering. Try this code:

```
app.get("/inbox", (req, res) => {
    imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
        connection.openBox("INBOX", (err, box) => {
            console.log(box.messages);
            res.locals.box_messages = box.messages;
            var searchCriteria = ["1:" + box.messages.total];
            var fetchOptions = {
                bodies: ["HEADER", "TEXT", ""],
            };

            connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(async function (messages) {
                var messagesList = {
                    messages: [],
                    subjects: [],
                    dates: [],
                    from: [],
                };
                for(let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    var all = _.find(item.parts, { which: "" });
                    var id = item.attributes.uid;
                    var idHeader = "Imap-Id: " + id + "\r\n";
                    try {
                        await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                            simpleParser(idHeader + all.body, (err, mail) => {
                                if (err) reject(err);
                                messagesList.messages.push(mail.html);
                                messagesList.subjects.push(mail.subject);
                                messagesList.dates.push(mail.date);
                                messagesList.messages.push(mail.from.text);
                                res.locals.messagesList = messagesList;
                                resolve(mail);
                            });
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        // handle error
                    }
                };
                res.render("index");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello , thanks for the code but not still working. 
I guess it will remain as a stackoverflow post that will never be resolved

Comment: try logging inside the map and then outside and check which one logs first

Comment: i tried but it first rendering index, after compile mailparser
I found some threads called async foreach on the internet. Maybe I should look at them?

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot to make the map callback async, try now.

Comment: I noticed that error and fixed it myself, but it still doesn't work. I couldn't understand why. I appreciate your help sir

Comment: You are right, i've just solved it. You need to change the map to a for, that should work

Comment: Try the edit i've just made

Comment: i tried but still errors

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I tried this time mailparser didn't work at all. If you want, I can post all the codes on discord.

Comment: I don't need all the code, I need the error logs you are getting

Comment: Missing error handling when `simplerParser()` rejects, when `connection.search()` has an error and when `imaps.connect()` has an error.

Comment: This `messages.lenght` is probably a typo.

Comment: i cant post from here wait a minutes

Comment: i have a ejs error messagesList of not defined

Comment: Try it now, i made a few edits

Comment: hi, i understood the problem. Our codes are correct, but we were getting an error because the library returned 'early' while processing the mail. I solved it with the help of counting with counter. Thanks for all